# How to create 1 instance of Azure Function per Azure Service Queue message

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, .net-4.8, azure-servicebus-queues

1. I am using Azure Service Bus Queue Triggered Azure Functions
2. Azure Function Runtime Version = 1 and running in consumption plan
3. Azure function and referenced projects are developed in .NET 4.8
4. I want to create 1 instance of Azure Function per Service Bus Queue message. Hence scaling 200 instances of Azure functions for 200 messages.
5. We explored Session based execution by setting sessionid of message and using IsSessionEnabled flag in azure function. But for this we need to upgrade Azure functions to runtime 4 and facing lot of challenges while upgrading packages.
6. We just can not upgrade to .NET 6 because i think we will have to upgrade referenced project to .NET 6 which we can not do at this stage.
7. We have set below properties , but its picking ONLY 1 message at a time and its not creating multiple instance
   `"maxConcurrentCalls": 1, "maxConcurrentSessions": 1, "maxMessageBatchSize": 1, "minMessageBatchSize": 1,`
8. We tried to set above appsettings in azure functions but its creating single instance. We want to create 1 instance of azure function per service bus queue message.
   We also tried settings sessionid ( which worked as expected in other project ) , but we had to upgrade to .NET6 which we can not do in this case

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: "For non-HTTP triggers, new instances are allocated, at most, once every 30 seconds." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling?tabs=azure-cli#understanding-scaling-behaviors

Comment: Define instance in this context, please.

Comment: jesse-squire : In consumption plan , Azure scales up max 200 instances of Azure Functions automatically, in that context i am talking about instances.
Like I said earlier , if we set unique sessionid while publishing message in Service Bus and  set maxConcurrentSessions = 1 , 1 Azure Function instance will process 1 message a time. So if there are 200 messages in service bus all having unique session id , azure will create 200 instances at same time

Comment: Why do you believe it's desirable to have 200 instances of a function rather than setting a concurrency value and allowing the host to manage the load?

Comment: jesse-squire - In My case logic inside my Azure function is driven by multiple flags , and hence the CPU and Memory utilization go up and dynamically depending upon the flags.
Hence I can not determine value of concurrency upfront and hence its safe to Process very message by  a separate instance of Azure Function.
I tried to set concurrency value , it works fine in some cases , in some cases memory goes beyond 1.5 GB and processing stalls or I get system.outofmemory error

Comment: From that description, Azure Functions is not the right platform for you.  It is not possible to do what you're looking to do unless you're willing to overprovision and set a constant number of instances equal to the exact number of messages that you'd want to process concurrently.